# Capitalizar string com caracteres acentuados

Tags: php, mysql, acentuação

Estou com um problema ao salvar palavras com acentos no MYSQL.

Meu banco está todo setado em `ut8_unicode_ci` e nas minhas páginas php tem `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Isso resolveu meu problema inicial com acentos, porém queria que os dados fossem salvos no banco apenas com a primeira letra de cada palavra maiúscula.

Encontrei a função `ucwords()` que resolveu meu problema, o usuário do sistema poderia digitar o nome do cliente todo em caixa alta que o sistema salva do jeito que eu queria no banco.

O problema é que se houver acentos no nome ele salva só até a última letra antes do acento. Ex: Se o nome for João da silva ele salva apena Jo. Gostaria de alguma ajuda com isso pois já estou há algum tempo pesquisando e ainda não consegui resolver isso. Segue abaixo um trecho do código:

```
function InsereMensalista()
{
    //TRAS AS VARIÁVEIS PARA O ESCOPO DA FUNÇÃO.
    global $conn, $nome, $email, $cpf, $rg, $tel, $celular, $celular2, $estado, $endereco, $bairro, $cidade, $placa1, $modelo1, $placa2, $modelo2, $mensalidade;

    //MUDA AS VARIÁVEIS PARA MINÚSCULO.
    $nome = strtolower($nome);
    $endereco = strtolower($endereco);
    $bairro = strtolower($bairro);
    $cidade = strtolower($cidade);
    $modelo1 = strtolower($modelo1);
    $modelo2 = strtolower($modelo2);

    // MUDA AS VARIÁVEIS COLOCANDO A PRIMEIRA LETRA DE CADA PALAVRA EM MAIÚsCULO ANTES DE INSERIR NO BANCO DE DADOS.
    $nome = ucwords($nome);
    $endereco = ucwords($endereco);
    $bairro = ucwords($bairro);
    $cidade = ucwords($cidade);
    $modelo1 = ucwords($modelo1);
    $modelo2 = ucwords($modelo2);

    //QUERY PARA INSERIR DADOS DIGITADOS NO FORMULÁRIO NO BANCO DE DADOS.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensalistas (id, nome, email, cpf, rg, telefone, celular, celular2, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado, placa1, modelo1, placa2, modelo2, mensalidade) 
    VALUES ('','$nome','$email','$cpf','$rg','$tel','$celular','$celular2','$endereco','$bairro','$cidade','$estado','$placa1','$modelo1','$placa2','$modelo2','$mensalidade')";

    //TENTA INSERIR OS DADOS NO BANCO DE DADOS.
    if($result = $conn->query($sql))
    {
        //EXIBE UM AVISO DE QUE O CADASTRO FOI EFETUADO COM SUCESSO.
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!');
        location.href='cadastro_mensalista.php';
        </script> ";
    }
    else
    {
        //EXIBE UM AVISO DE QUE O USUÁRIO TENTOU INSERIR DADOS JÁ REGISTRADOS NO BANCO DE DADOS.
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Você tentou inserir dados já cadastrados. Verifique os dados do cliente e tente novamente!');
        location.href='javascript:window.history.go(-1)';
        </script> ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Já experimentaste o `mysqli_real_escape_string` ?

Comment: O problema é com o ucwords acredito eu. O que o `mysqli_real_escape_string` influencia?

Comment: @Weverton, pelos meus testes e bem provavel que não seja o ucwords o causador do seu problema, veja o teste: https://ideone.com/XfjzKQ você já tentou ir printando parte por parte do seu código para ver onde a informação se perde ?

Comment: Então estou testando aqui percebi que o problema é no strtolower(). Só com o ucwords ele gravou normal, inseri os dados: "joao, joão, Joao, João, JOAO, JOÃO" e ele gravou no mysql isso: Joao, João, Joao, João, JOAO, JOÃO" Ou seja colocou a primeira letra maiúscula corretamente, o problema é que eu não queria que ele salvasse o nome todo em caixa alta. Se o usuário digitar "JOÃO" ele teria que salvar "João", pra isso usei o strtolower(), e ai ele salva só "Jo".

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta api também: https://market.mashape.com/semantics/accentwords

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ucwords()` é uma das funções para manipulação de strings do php que não suporta multibyte por isso ela não consegue converter caracteres acentuados ou de outras linguas.

Para cada função que manipula string existe uma cópia que trabalha com caracteres multibyte, essas funções tem o prefixo `mb`.

Para capitalizar sua string use a função [mb_convert_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) e informe o segundo argumento como `MB_CASE_TITLE` outras opções são `MB_CASE_UPPER` e `MB_CASE_LOWER`

```
<?php 

$str = 'teste éverdade bla bla óooo ýabc';
echo mb_convert_case($str,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
echo ucwords($str);
```

Saída:

```
Teste Éverdade Bla Bla Óooo Ýabc
Teste éverdade Bla Bla óooo ýabc
```

Comment: Tentei mas não deu certo cara coloquei outra resposta pra vc ver. Obrigado.

Comment: Cara com base na sua resposta resolvi pesquisar sobre a função mb_strtolower e consegui resolver meu problema. $nome = mb_strtolower($nome,'UTF-8'); Deu certinho muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @WevertonJúnior porque converter para minusculo?

Comment: @rray, se ele tiver problemas, a única coisa que você precisa fazer é passar o terceiro parâmetro, que é a codificação. Sendo assim: `mb_convert_case($str,  MB_CASE_TITLE, 'utf-8')`

Comment: +1 Essa função é utilizada internamente pelo Laravel, no método `Str::title`

Comment: @rray eu preciso converter para minúsculo porque não quero que salve no banco tudo em caixa alta. Só com o ucwords se o usuário digitar o nome do cliente: JOÃO SILVA eu preciso que salve no banco sempre João Silva. A função ucwords funcionou bem mudando "joão silva" para "João Silva" mas se o usuário digitasse tudo em caixa alta o problema ocorria justo na hora de usar a strtolower() em palavras com acento, e o BD salvava só "Jo". Mas seguindo sua explicação das funções mb_ cheguei nesse resultado que resolveu meu problema: $nome = ucwords(mb_strtolower($nome,'UTF-8')); Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Até agora não entendi para que você quer usar ucwords, sendo que já tem `mb_convert_case`.  É desnecessário fazer isso, @WevertonJúnior. Essa função que o @rray falou tem que funcionar corretamente, ou então está havendo um erro de comunicação

Comment: @WevertonJúnior é so usar o mb_convert_case, não precisa do mb_strlower, faz um teste simples, `echo mb_convert_case('AÇÃO', MB_CASE_TITLE);`

Comment: Então @rray, colocquei jeito que você falou (copiei e colei) e ele exibiu na tela "A??ÃO e quanto coloquei $nome = mb_convert_case('AÇÃO', MB_CASE_TITLE) ele gravou só A no BD. Mas não sei bem porque da outra forma: $nome = ucwords(mb_strtolower($nome,'UTF-8')); Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @WevertonJúnior, pode ser o encode do seu arquivo, ele deve estar como utf-8