# Insert no mysql com strtoupper não esta aceitando números e letras

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou fazendo o seguinte insert:

```
<?php 
include "conexao.php";
  $v_tipo         = $_POST ["tipo"];
  $v_funcao       = $_POST ["funcao"];
  $v_numero       = $_POST ["numero"];
  $v_responsavel  = strtoupper($_POST['responsavel']);
  $v_tag          = strtoupper($_POST['tag']);
  $v_loja         = $_POST ["loja"];
  $v_local        = strtoupper($_POST['local']);
  $v_conteudo     = strtoupper($_POST['conteudo']);


      $insert = "INSERT INTO refrigeracao 
                                (refri_id,
                         refri_tipo,
                         refri_funcao,
                         refri_numero,
                         refri_responsavel,
                         refri_tag,
                         refri_loja,                         
                         refri_local,
                         refri_conteudo) 
                           VALUES (NULL,
                                   '$v_tipo',
                                   '$v_funcao',
                                   '$v_numero',
                                   '$v_responsavel',
                                   '$v_tag',
                                   '$v_loja',
                                   '$v_conteudo',
                                   '$v_local')"; 

            mysql_query($insert);


 echo '<script>alert(\'Dados cadastrados com sucesso!\');parent.location =\'index.php\';</script>';

?>
```

E estou usando o `strtoupper` para quando o usuário digitar letras minusculas automaticamente salva-las em maiúsculas,quando o campo é somente texto esta dando certo,mais no caso da  `$v_tag          = strtoupper($_POST['tag']);` que é números e letras esta salvando somente os números,o que pode estar errado ?

Comment: Da um exemplo desse `tag` é para funcionar, outras opção são [mb_convert_case](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94571/91) ou fazer isso no banco de dados.

Comment: `refri_tag` é varchar?

Comment: sim é varchar sim

Comment: exemplo como salvaria:  1C2B33CD mesmo se o usuário digitasse 1c2b33cd

Comment: O problema não parece ser esse código, faz direto no banco, lá no insert mude para: `upper('$v_tag'),`

Comment: perfeito. Obrigado. Mais depois vou ver a documentação PHP e vejo porque da outra forma não deu certo,mais direto no banco foi. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Então, a descrição do problema não bate com o código, parece ter algo externo causando essa situação.

Comment: Como assim,não entendi bem,poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: Recomendação de leitura : [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/14213)

Comment: Por exemplo execute,  `echo strtoupper('ação 2015');`, não conveter os caracteres acentudos é esperado, porém 'cortar' as letras não, por isso disse, parecesse que tem algo externo interferindo.

Comment: Entendi,vou analisar com calma e caso encontre algo irei postar.

Comment: @Guilherme Lautert  Ótimo artigo,já estou mesmo estudando o PDO para migração. Obrigado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [php strtoupper() com acentos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84100/php-strtoupper-com-acentos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outra forma de resolver esse problema é utilizar a função `upper()` do MySQL assim a string é convertida já no insert.

Exemplo:

```
select upper('1c2b33cd') #1C2B33CD
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra solução é utilizar a função [mb_strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) do `PHP`

Comment: Vou testar também é retorno.